# Can GoogleAPIClient notify you when an API becomes available?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client

I have a wearable app that gets launched at device boot time and runs continually.

When it launches its possible that the wearable API is not available as part of GoogleAPIClient, but it may become available later if the user installs the Android Wear app.

Is there any way my app can register to be notified if the wearable Api becomes available (or unavailable)?

Comment: What cases are you running into where the Wearable API is not available on a Wearable app?

Comment: Its not actually a wearable app, its a large phone app, a small part of which has functionality that extends from the phone onto a watch if the user has one. The main phone app is perfectly capable of fully functioning without the wearable portion if there is no wearable device. Therefore the app can run without the user having installed Android Wear.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would cause the Wearable API to become available is through an update to Google Play services. When Google Play services is updated, your existing connected would be closed. Reconnecting would then show the new API as available.

Comment: Thanks, but if the Wearable API is the only one I'm using and its unavailable then I wouldn't be able to obtain a connection in the first place so I wouldn't be able to monitor its closing.

Comment: If you're using [addApiIfAvailable()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addApiIfAvailable(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api<O>,%sO,%scom.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope...)) you can certainly connect your `GoogleApiClient` without a connected API.

Comment: I've discovered that the API can be available but the connection could still fail with SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.